# Mediawiki offline editor

Tags: cross-platform, mediawiki, text-editor

Is there an offline mediawiki editor (for wikisource.org) that fulfills following requirements:

1. cross-platform (Linux/Windows).
2. capable to work offline most of the time and upload(sync) once there is a connection to Internet.
3. not WYSIWG, but with a GUI.

Comment: Software recommendations are strictly off topic here. You may get some joy at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, do read their literature first to make sure you're asking in the right way

Comment: I see the "Related" section on the right side of the page - and there a lot of software recommendation questions. Is it a new rule?

Comment: I don't know exactly when it was introduced, at least several years ago though

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a java desktop client for Wikisource a couple of years ago, but it never got far. I'll see if I can dig up the code, and add something to enws.

One other possibility would be working with a DjVu editor, and correcting the text layer in a DjVu file before uploading it to Wikisource. Of course, it'd no longer match exactly what's in the DjVu, but that mightn't matter.